# Pulling Data from JSON Array to make 3 different Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make three arrays based on the JSON Data that I'm pulling from my restaurant. I want to have an array of Entre, Main, & Dessert that will display in a tableView Object. This is the code I'm using to pull in data:

```
func loadMeals() {
    Helpers.showActivityIndicator(activityIndicator, view)

    if let restaurantId = restaurant?.id {
        APIManager.shared.getMeals(restaurantId: restaurantId, completionHandler: { (json) in
            if json != nil {
                self.meals = []

                if let tempMeals = json["meals"].array {
                    for item in tempMeals {
                        let meal = Meal(json: item)
                        self.meals.append(meal)
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    Helpers.hideActivityIndicator(self.activityIndicator)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Item prints out:

```
items {
  "name" : "Spinach Artichoke",
  "course" : "entres",
  "short_description" : "savory",
  "id" : 20,
  "image" : "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/media\/product_images\/artichoke.jpg",
  "usage" : "homestyle",
  "sizes" : [
    {
      "size" : 3,
      "id" : 24,
      "product_id" : 20,
      "price" : 55.899999999999999
    },
    {
      "size" : 4,
      "id" : 25,
      "product_id" : 20,
      "price" : 78
    },
    {
      "size" : 5,
      "id" : 26,
      "product_id" : 20,
      "price" : 125
    }
  ]
}
items {
  "name" : "Pizza",
  "course" : "main",
  "short_description" : "Melty cheese",
  "id" : 19,
  "image" : "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/media\/product_images\/pizza.jpg",
  "usage" : "top",
  "sizes" : [
    {
      "size" : 6,
      "id" : 23,
      "product_id" : 19,
      "price" : 75.989999999999995
    }
  ]
}
items {
  "name" : "Chocolate Mousee Devil's cake",
  "course" : "dessert",
  "short_description" : "Sweet And Smooth",
  "id" : 18,
  "image" : "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/media\/product_images\/Devils_cake.jpg",
  "usage" : "sweets",
  "sizes" : [
    {
      "size" : 2,
      "id" : 20,
      "product_id" : 18,
      "price" : 50
    },
    {
      "size" : 3,
      "id" : 21,
      "product_id" : 18,
      "price" : 120
    },
    {
      "size" : 4,
      "id" : 22,
      "product_id" : 18,
      "price" : 376
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create the arrays by pulling the data from this function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would you like your array to be exactly like? Can you give a format example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just You need to **group By** `course`

meals Array  will be  `[[String:Any]]`   Key will be `course`  `Any` will be Array of `course` items

```
  func loadMeals() {
         Helpers.showActivityIndicator(activityIndicator, view)

          if let restaurantId = restaurant?.id {
                    APIManager.shared.getMeals(restaurantId: restaurantId, completionHandler: { (json) in
                        if json != nil {
                            self.meals = []

                            if let tempMeals = json["meals"].array {
                               self.meals =  Dictionary(grouping: tempMeals, by: { $0["course"] as! String })
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                Helpers.hideActivityIndicator(self.activityIndicator)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

**OutPut Console:**

```
["Main": [["name": Chocolate Mousee Devil's cake, "course": Main, "short_description": Sweet And Smooth, "id": 18, "image": http://localhost:8000/media/product_images/Devils_cake.jpg, "usage": sweets, "sizes": <__NSArrayI 0x60c0002456a0>(
{
    id = 20;
    price = 50;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 2;
},
{
    id = 21;
    price = 120;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 3;
},
{
    id = 22;
    price = 376;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 4;
}
)
]], "dessert": [["name": Chocolate Mousee Devil's cake, "course": dessert, "short_description": Sweet And Smooth, "id": 18, "image": http://localhost:8000/media/product_images/Devils_cake.jpg, "usage": sweets, "sizes": <__NSArrayI 0x60c000243d50>(
{
    id = 20;
    price = 50;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 2;
},
{
    id = 21;
    price = 120;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 3;
},
{
    id = 22;
    price = 376;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 4;
}
)
], ["name": Chocolate Mousee Devil's cake, "course": dessert, "short_description": Sweet And Smooth, "id": 18, "image": http://localhost:8000/media/product_images/Devils_cake.jpg, "usage": sweets, "sizes": <__NSArrayI 0x60c000248910>(
{
    id = 20;
    price = 50;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 2;
},
{
    id = 21;
    price = 120;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 3;
},
{
    id = 22;
    price = 376;
    "product_id" = 18;
    size = 4;
}
)
]]]
```

Comment: I intended to use separators in the tableview to announce the specific kind of meal. Is it possible to do that if the array shows all items?

Comment: I split your data to be key and items do arrange your code to section table by course key

Comment: I'm trying this now but, "jsonDictionary" doesnt seem to be a valid key. I've imported swiftyJson but, it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry jsonDicyionary is my own I fix it check update

Comment: Thanks. Let me know when you've figured it out.

Comment: Thanks. For that. Now I get this error: Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<String, [JSON]>' to type '[Meal]'

Comment: I told you to change meal in answer to be array of dictionary

Comment: This Line: "self.meals =  Dictionary(grouping: tempMeals, by: { $0["course"] as! String })" - Gives the error

Comment: Please read my answer  you have to change meals array to be ‘[[String:[String:Any]]]’

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171034/discussion-between-a-true-novice-and-abdelahad-darwish).